# Cropping large background image

Tags: android

I have two situations/projects where I have to use a large bitmap as background activity.

The first project ports a WP7 application to Android! The WP7 app is using a panorama control with a bitmap as large as 3 screens. I would like to reuse the large bitmap similar in a way that I use the left part for the first activity, the middle part for the second activity and the right part for the third activity. In other words I would like to define which part to crop.

In the second project we try to develop an app which should run on various screen sizes (including tablet), the app should also use a background image. Is it a good idea to provide only one picture with a quadratic size (as long as the largest screen width) and use this picture through every resolution and just crop the background image depending on the actual size of the display?

- Is it possible to crop pictures on Android?
- Is it possible to define the part of the picture which is kept?
- Is it possible to use this croped pictures as background image or may I encounter performance penalties?
- What do you think of this technique? Is it a good idea?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

answering your questions:

1. yes it is possible to crop pictures in Android (I've done so)
2. you can define wich part of the picture is shown in  each activity
   with a `canvas` and only drawing the `rect` that corresponds to the part
   of the image that you want to display (eventough I wouldnt suggest
   the approach of having diferent activities with the "same" content)
3. yes, you can use cropped pictures as background image for whatever
   you want. Once you cropped the image use that `bitmap` and save it in
   the device and then you might use it as you wish, and eventought is not recommended to have the whole image as background you can do so.
4. I suggest that you use a [`SurfaceView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) since you will be able to move it (the image) all around the screen without having to create a new activity. Here is a good tutorial to `SurfaceView` [Playing with graphics in Android – Part I](http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html) and this approach will also work with Tablets.